# Mendeleydesktop does not load full screen on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qt, i3-wm, compositing, mendeley

I have been using `MendeleyDesktop 1.17.9` for a while, but for some reason this week the app is not loading properly. For some reason it seems to only load part of the screen and it will not let me resize the window. I have included a picture below as well. I also use the `i3` windows manager.
[image]

I also included the messages on from the command line when I directly invoke mendeleydesktop.

Not clear on what is causing the problem. I also have the export of the commandline info for the app too. I am not really familiar with `Qt` so could not really decipher any qt specific messages.

```
** (mendeleydesktop.x86_64:26814): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-gHpyHyqp9Y: Connection refused
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to ToolBarActionWidget "", which already has a layout
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to ToolBarActionWidget "", which already has a layout
Qt WebEngine data directory not found at location /opt/mendeley/desktop/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64. Trying application directory...
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /opt/mendeley/desktop/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/krishnab/apps/mendeleydesktop-1.15.3-linux-x86_64/lib/mendeleydesktop/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
[0601/140729:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
Qt WebEngine data directory not found at location /opt/mendeley/desktop/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine Plugins directory not found. Trying fallback directory... Plugins as for example video codecs MAY NOT work.
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /opt/mendeley/desktop/Qt/5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/krishnab/apps/mendeleydesktop-1.15.3-linux-x86_64/lib/mendeleydesktop/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
[0601/140729:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
```

I have tried a few different ways to resolve this.
1. rebooting the computer
2. reinstalling mendeleydesktop
3. reinstalling qt5

But none of these have worked. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I thought it might be a compositing error or something, but not sure how to fix that. This error does not happen with any application other than mendeleydesktop.

Comment: Have you tried to make the  *MendeleyDesktop* window floating? By default this can be done with **$mod**+**Shift**+**Space** (where **$mod** is your chosen modifier key). Some applications have … issues with the way *i3* tries to (re-)size their windows in the tiling layer.